# Assign a signature per contact in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, email-signature

[This Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/180628/14596) asks something similar, but it was related to Outlook and without an applicable answer.

Is there a way to to store a signature preference on a per contact basis? Or does anyone know of an extension to do something like this?

If you write to your mother, child, co-worker, vendor, or customer they all don't all expect the same thing. A custom field can be assigned to a contact, could that or another field be used somehow?

I just want to assign a specific signature to a user. Very similar to the way a custom ringtone can be assigned to a contact on a phone.

Answer (score 5):

Signatures are tied to the `from:` address you're using. You can use so-called "plus addressing" to define multiple different addresses that are actually just your address and assign signatures to each.

Here's an example:

1. Go to `Settings | Accounts and Import`
2. Click "Add another email address you own"
3. In the `Email address:` field, put `username+mom@gmail.com`

   - Normally you'd have to verify this address, but Google is smart enough to know that this is just your regular address
   - Obviously, put your actual username in instead of "username"
4. Go to `Settings | General` and go down the the "Signature" section
5. Change the dropdown to be the email address you just created
6. Modify your signature to whatever you like

   - How about "I love you Mom!"?

Now, when you send a message to Mom, just be sure to change the `from:` address to be the special address for Mom. Then your custom signature will be included.

One nice feature is that when Mom replies to that address, assuming you have turned on "When replying to a message: Reply from the same address the message was sent to" when you reply back this address will already be selected.

Comment: well I have played with this and the one issue is having to have 10 different accounts as signatures. If there is no other way, this might be what I need to do. It is remembering to select the right from: that is the problem. Seems like somehting a computer should do for me  Thanks

Comment: It's less than ideal, yes. But since you can't tie a signature to a contact, it's either this or using the canned responses.

Comment: thanks. I wonder if creating an extension is possible. That is what I was hoping to hear was possible. May look into doing that

Comment: @datatoo Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: nope, I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly using Gmail signatures but you can hack one of the Gmail Labs tools.

- Goto Settings, enable 'Canned Responses' and save.
- Now open the compose window and type out your email signature.
- Click the down arrow next to the trash icon on the compose window.
- Select 'New canned response' under the Save section and name your signature.

TO use the signature, open the canned response tab and select the appropriate signature from the insert section.

Couple of things to keep in mind.

- You need to add the signature manually.
- And you'll need to add the signature before typing out the rest of your email.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestion, but was really hoping to auto-assign a signature based upon who is being addressed. I could use shortcut abbreviations too, but it would be really nice to save the appropriate signature with the contact